# Supersolvable groups

Tags: group-theory

I would like to find an exact sequence $1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 1$ of groups where $N,Q$ are [supersolvable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolvable_group) and G is not. I found it but in my example $G$ is finite, I was wondering if you have a nice example with $G$ an infinite group, I tried with a lot of groups without finding it. Do you have any idea?

EDIT: Suppose that $G$ is a finite not supersolvable group and we have an exact sequence $1\rightarrow K\rightarrow G\rightarrow G/K\rightarrow 1$ with $K$ and $G/K$ supersolvable. Define $G^\prime=G\times\mathbb{Z}$, then $G^\prime$ is not supersolvable because if I have a normal-cyclic series the I project it on $G$ and I obtain a normal-cyclic series for $G$ and this is a contradiction. So I can take $1\rightarrow K\times\{0\}\rightarrow G\rightarrow G/(K\times\{0\})\rightarrow1$. Now $K\times\{0\}$ is supersolvable and $G/(K\times\{0\})\cong (G/K)\times\mathbb{Z}$ and it's supersolvable, am I right?

Comment: Couldn't you enlarge your class of examples by taking a direct sum with any finitely generated abelian group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a more essentially infinite example, you could take a semidirect product of ${\mathbb Z}^2$ by ${\mathbb Z}$ with an irreducible action. For example $\langle x,y,z \mid xy=yx, z^{-1}xz=y, z^{-1}yz=xy \rangle$.

Comment: how did you create this example?